# How can I know user to click btnFinish button in several Activities?

Tags: android

The activity1 open activity2 when click btnNext button in activity1.
The activity2 open activity3 and will be closed when click btnNext button in activity2.
The activity3 will be closed when I click btnFinish or btnCancel button.

I think the activity1 will be shown when activity3 is closed. I hope activity1 to do something  when user click btnFinish button in activity3, how can I know user to click  btnFinish button in activity3?

```
public class activity1  extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);       

        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(),
                        ui.activity2.class);
         startActivityForResult(intent, 20); 
            }
        }); 

    }
}

public class activity2  extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);       

        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(),
                        ui.activity2.class);
         startActivityForResult(intent, 30); 
                 finish();
            }
        }); 

    }
}


public class activity3  extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity3);       

        Button btnFinish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFinish);
        btnbtnFinish.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent();  
         intent.putExtra("smsid", id);
         setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);  
         finish();                  
            }
        }); 

       Button btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {               
         finish();                  
            }
        }); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**
You can use [LocalBroadCastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to send a local broadcast to classes within your project. Inside the `Activity 1`, you can start listing for broadcast as soon as you start `activity 2`. Then when the user clicks `finish` button on `activity 3`, you can send a local broadcast before finishing that activity. You `activity 1` receive it and based on the broadcast, you can so something in the `activity 1`.

Read answer on [how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager) to know how you can use it.

**Method 2:**  You can finish `activity1` as soon as you start `activity 2`. Then when from your 3rd activity, user clicks `finish`, then you can start `activity 1` again using `Intent` and `extras`. In the extras you can mention something to detect that user has clicked `finish`. Then in the `activity 1` `onCreate()` you can read the extra value and come to know that user click `finish` in previous activity and you can so something based on that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: BTW, Is thanhnh's way good ? I think it will make screen splash.  Because Activity2 keep open, Activity2 will be opened then closed when you close Activity3,

Comment: Can I use LocalBroadCastManager in Android 2.3.6 ?

Comment: You can use it. Although not sure but you might require android's v4 support library for lower version. You would have to check

Comment: Could you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045335/does-localbroadcastmanager-only-work-in-the-one-activity ? Thanks!

Comment: @user828896 Answered there. Hope its more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Other way. You don't need to `finish()` the Activity2 after open the Activity3.

So when the Activity3 calls  `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);`  `finish();`, your program will reopen the Activity2.

in Activity2 you must override the `onActivityResult()` method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 30) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);  
              finish();///---> finish the activity 2 and go back the activity 1
        }
    }
}
```

In Activity1 you will recive the result in `onActivityResult()` as Activity2